# Can this inequality be solved with Mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, derivatives

As my sub-assignment I have to solve inequality:

$$
\ln\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right) -\frac{1}{x + 1} > 0
$$

If I understood MVT correctly, I *should* set $g(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x} + 1\right) -\frac{1}{x + 1}$ and choose my interval $(0,x)$ to get $g(0)=0$ so: $$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = g'(x) \Leftrightarrow xg'(x) = g(x)$$ and get that $g'(x)>0$ and $x$ is also $>0$ $\implies g(x)>0$.

So that should be some ideal case, but I cant use it for this assignment ($g(0)$ doesn't exist). Did I misunderstood something about this and it is leading me on wrong path?

*EDIT*

$x\in(0,\infty)$

Comment: What do you know about $x$? Of course this inequality doesn't holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for example $x=-1$.

Comment: I would begin by examining $g'(x)$ to see where the function is increasing vs. decreasing.

Comment: $g'(x)$ is always $<0$

Comment: It's worth noting that $g(0)$ isn't $0,$ as written. In fact, $g(0)$ isn't even defined.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your inequality holds true for $x>0$. Then rewrite
$$
\log \left(\frac{1}{x}+1 \right) = \log \frac{x+1}{x}=\log(x+1)-\log x.
$$
Now
$$
\log(x+1)-\log x = \frac{1}{x+\xi}
$$
for some $0<\xi<1$, by the MVT applied to $g(x)=\log x$ on $[x,x+1]$. But then
$$
\frac{1}{x+\xi} > \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x>0$ we have:
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\log(x+1)-\log(x)=\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}>\frac{1}{x+1}$$
since $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Exploiting the convexity of $f$, we can also state:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)>\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>\frac{1}{x+1/2}.$$